Predicted output is only 0s
I am developing a neural network using Home credit Default Risk Dataset.
The prediction should be between 0.0 and 1.0 but my algorithm's outcome is just 0.0 for every row.
My Code
# Assuming final_train_df and final_test_df are already loaded and cleaned dataframes
categorical_columns = ['NAME_CONTRACT_TYPE', 'CODE_GENDER', 'FLAG_OWN_CAR', 'FLAG_OWN_REALTY', 
                       'NAME_TYPE_SUITE', 'NAME_INCOME_TYPE', 'NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE', 
                       'NAME_FAMILY_STATUS', 'NAME_HOUSING_TYPE', 'WEEKDAY_APPR_PROCESS_START', 'ORGANIZATION_TYPE']

# StringIndexer and OneHotEncoder for categorical columns
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=col, outputCol=col + '_index', handleInvalid='skip') for col in categorical_columns]
encoders = [OneHotEncoder(inputCol=col + '_index', outputCol=col + '_ohe') for col in categorical_columns]

# Create a pipeline for encoding
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders)

# Fit and transform the training data
train_df = pipeline.fit(final_train_df).transform(final_train_df)
# Transform the test data using the same fitted pipeline
test_df = pipeline.fit(final_train_df).transform(final_test_df)

# Drop the original and indexed categorical columns
cols_to_drop = categorical_columns + [col + '_index' for col in categorical_columns]
train_df = train_df.drop(*cols_to_drop)
test_df = test_df.drop(*cols_to_drop)

# Cast specific columns to double
columns_to_cast = ['AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_HOUR', 'AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_DAY', 'AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_WEEK',
                   'AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_MON', 'AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_QRT', 'AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR']

for col_name in columns_to_cast:
    train_df = train_df.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast("double"))
    test_df = test_df.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast("double"))

print("Encoding complete")

# Assemble feature vector
ohe_columns = [col + '_ohe' for col in categorical_columns]
numerical_columns = [col for col in train_df.columns if col not in ohe_columns + ['SK_ID_CURR', 'TARGET']]

print(f"Numerical columns: {numerical_columns}")
print(f"One-hot encoded columns: {ohe_columns}")

# Remove existing 'features' and 'scaled_features' columns if they exist
for col in ['features', 'scaled_features']:
    if col in train_df.columns:
        train_df = train_df.drop(col)
    if col in test_df.columns:
        test_df = test_df.drop(col)

print("assembling feature vector")
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=numerical_columns + ohe_columns, outputCol="features")
train_df = assembler.transform(train_df)
test_df = assembler.transform(test_df)
print("Feature vector assembly complete.")



print("Scaling The features...")
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaled_features")
scaler_model = scaler.fit(train_df)
train_df = scaler_model.transform(train_df)
test_df = scaler_model.transform(test_df)
print("Scaling complete.")


# Neural Network Structure

layers = [
    173,           # Number of input features -> Check from the above Statement
    64,            # Hidden layer size
    32,            # Hidden layer size
    2              # Number of classes
]

print(f"Neural network layers: {layers}")

print ("Initialization of  Multilayer Perceptron Classifier")
mlp = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(
    featuresCol='scaled_features',
    labelCol='TARGET',
    maxIter=100,
    layers=layers,
    blockSize=128,
    seed=1234
)

print("Training the model...")
mlp_model = mlp.fit(train_df)
print("Model training complete.")

print("Making predictions on the training set and checking for Overfitting/Underfitting...")
train_predictions = mlp_model.transform(train_df)

print("Evaluating the model...")
# Evaluate the model
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(labelCol='TARGET', rawPredictionCol='rawPrediction', metricName='areaUnderROC')
auc_train = evaluator.evaluate(train_predictions)
print(f'Training AUC: {auc_train}')

print("Making predictions on the test set...")
# Make predictions on the test set 
test_predictions = mlp_model.transform(test_df)

# Show the predictions
test_predictions.select('SK_ID_CURR', 'prediction', 'probability').show()

print("Preparing the submission file...")

# Prepare the submission file
submission = test_predictions.select('SK_ID_CURR', 'prediction')
submission.show()

# Write the DataFrame to a temporary directory
temp_path = './temp_prediction'
submission.write.csv(temp_path, header=True)
combined_df = spark.read.csv(temp_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
combined_df = combined_df.repartition(1)
final_path = './final_prediction.csv'
combined_df.write.csv(final_path, header=True)

print("Single CSV file saved.")

outcome of the code: 
I have tried chanigng some parameters of the NN algorithm, and also i have detected some outliers and deleted them.
What could i check?
UPDATE 1:
AUC = 0.748


What is the AUC?

@Dave The AUC on Training Dataset is 0.7487. I am updating the Quesiton above

A ROCAUC of $0.7487$ is decent, certainly enough to say that the model is finding some way to distinguish between the two categories (at least in-sample). The fact that the categorical predictions are always the same means that the classification rule on top of the raw model predictions is assigning everything to the same category, despite the raw predictions having differences that yield a decent ROCAUC.
See this question for a discussion of how to get from raw predictions to classifications by using a threshold. It seems that your raw predictions all lie below the default threshold, a situation not so uncommon when there is class imbalance. Maybe consider not using the default threshold, perhaps not even using thresholds at all and evaluating the raw model predictions.
You are looking at default risk. Most borrowers do not default (class imbalance), so the odds are kind of always against defaulting. The classification threshold is a probability of $0.5$ in most software (but there is no rule of math saying you must use this threshold). Is it so surprising that no one is predicted to default with at least a $50\%$ chance when defaulting is generally uncommon?

so what you suggest in here as i understand is to add a Threshold over 0.5 that will help the model make more accurate predictions. You also mention that there's is an imbalance in the dataset ( I can verify too ). Do you belive balancing the data would be a good approach?

@Erevos I would recommend a threshold lower than 1/2, not greater, but directly evaluating the raw probability predictions without using any kind of threshold has major advantages. As far as balancing the data goes, that’s almost never a good idea. Class imbalance is rarely a real problem (as much as people often incorrectly believe it is), and misleading the model won’t solve a non-problem.

@Erevos Regarding class imbalance often being mistaken for a problem, this question of mine with a bountied answer gets into more detail about why this rumor persists and when imbalance might really be a problem (not the norm, but it does happen).

Thank you @Dave! over the next days i will keep on studying around this topic, and if i am still unable to correct my code, i may ask more questions in here :)
